# Can't login after suspending Ubuntu, No tty login prompt either

Tags: 22.04, login, suspend, tty, fsck

I have installed Ubuntu 22.04 alongside Windows 11 on my Asus Vivobook 16x Notebook powered by Ryzen 5 series processor.

I noticed that if I *suspend* it or it *gets locked automatically* after screen is turned off, I am not able to login. It shows the login screen and I can enter the password but it never logs me in or says anything about password being incorrect. There is one weird thing though; in this situation my mouse pointer also becomes kind of a square. Also when I try to access tty by pressing `Ctrl+Alt+F4` it shows a lot of error messages like this:

[image]

and never gives me the prompt to login into system.

But if I simply ***lock* the screen myself** then I can login normally.

I want to point one more thing that earlier, due to some unknown reasons, the internal ssd of my system has failed once. I got it replaced with a new one. I am do not have any clue about the `systemd-journal` message but seeing the `EXT4-fs error` there, is it related to hard disk?
Has anybody faced this problem? What could be causing this? Could it be solved by using a live-USB and doing a simple `fsck` check?

Comment: It looks like a hardware error, because the file system reverts to read-only at this point. A `fsck`, either immediately after bootup (before the desktop environment kicks in) or after booting from a Live USB stick, will show whether your disk is failing (and may even solve the problem), or if something else is going on.

Comment: I did try to run `fsck` during boot (by selecting safe-mode) but it does not proceed with the check because somehow ubuntu partition was already mounted at that point; I don't know how that is even possible though. So I am thinking of trying to use a Live USB. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: I think the standard way to force a `fsck` at startup, before the file system is mounted for general use, is to add a parameter `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet fsck.mode=force"` to `/etc/default/grub`, then executing `sudo update-grub`, then rebooting. This causes all `ext4` file systems to be `fsck`'ed. However, it's safer to use the Live USB method.

Comment: OK, so I got the problem solved by using a live USB. The SSD was somehow damaged so I got it replaced from the manufacturer.